# How many n satisfy this condition?

Tags: number-theory

How many $n$ (natural number) satisfies this condition:
$$2^{n} + 3^{n} = \beta \cdot7, \beta  \in  N$$
In another words, how many $n$ is possible in such a way that this number is divisible by seven?
I am really poor in the theory of numbers/figures, so I would appreciate a tip.

Comment: What have you tried ? do you know Fermat little theorem ?

Comment: Hello, the only thing i realized is that the unit figure the sum are 7 or 3, and knowing a number is divisible by 7 if, being n the number, n-2*i is divisible by 7, where i is the unit figure. But this helps nothing. No, i do not know this theorem, i will google it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP does not seem to know FLT, I would suggest the following:

Prove by induction that $2^{3+6k}+3^{3+6k}$ is divisible by $7$ for all $k\geq 0$.

Comment: This does not show ALL $n$'s satisfying the property have the form of $3+6k$. One cannot avoid FLT to prove it rigorously, in my opinion.

Comment: Agreed, but that's not OP's question. I understood "how much" as: are there finitely many or infinitely many such $n$...

Answer (score 1):

I hope this answer may serve as a complement to GreginGre's. We would like to show his answer does give all desired $n$'s.

**Fermat's Little Theorem (Special case):**  $2^{6k} \equiv 3^{6k} \equiv 1 \: \text{(mod 7)}$ for any natural number $k$.

**Proof.** By direct calculation, $2^6 \equiv 64 \equiv 1  \: \text{(mod 7)}$. So for any natural number $k$, we have $2^{6k} \equiv (2^{6})^{k} \equiv 1^{k} \equiv 1  \: \text{(mod 7)}$. One  can prove similarly for $3$.

FLT basically shows the periodicity of $2^n + 3^n  \text{(mod 7)}$ (as a congruence class modulo $7$). Since the period is $6$, it suffices to check for $n = 0,1,\dots,5$. After some computation, one finds $3$ is the only candidate.